# How do I add add a new array at the end of an existing array starting with a comma using a form?

Tags: php

I'm trying to submit a form along with the "First" & "Last" name, when the form is submitted, How do I insert those new names into the existing array starting with a comma (so the PHP file doesn't break with white blank space).

I've tried this several times, but no use at all.

This is the PHP file called: "**Arrays.php**"

```
<?php
    $array_demo = array
    (
        // list of peoples names
        'John' => 'Wright'
    );
?>
```

This is the HTML form called: **index.php**

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
<input type="text" name="lastname"><br>
<button type="submit">Add Names</button>
</form>
```

Any suggestions fellow StackOverflow Members? Trying to add those submitted-form fields inside an existing array as shown above.

Comment: where do you want to store the array? in a PHP file?

Comment: The php code above is the php file, example: "Array.php"

Comment: do you want to store the array back in the file?

Comment: Basically, when the form is submitted, I want those fields to be stored in the Arrays.php file along with other existing names.

Comment: OK, I got the question. Check my answer. There I have suggested a better way. which is more human readable & give a better performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is JSON serializing. It is more human readable and you'll get better performance. I do not know why you are trying to save the array itself in the php file.

```
$array_demo = array('John' => 'Wright');

//if you want to add a new name, Then you can do
$array_demo[$_POST['firstname']]= $_POST['lastname'];

//Then store the array to a file
file_put_contents("array.json",json_encode($array_demo));
# array.json => {"John":"Wright"}

//Then you can load the file back to an array
$array_demo = json_decode(file_get_contents('array.json'), true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, you know the second line of the code? How come my PHP marks this line as an error? ($array_demo[{$_POST['firstname']}]= $_POST['lastname'];)- sorry, I never used JSON before on Apache via Localhost

Comment: JSON - why? where is the javascript in this question ?

Comment: JSON is not only limited to js. It is platform independent.

Comment: yea J just happens to stand for JavaScript ;)

Answer (score 1):

to match the current structure you can do this

```
$array_demo[{$_POST['firstname']}]= $_POST['lastname'];
```

but remember keys are unique so you could not have 2 people with the same first name

EXPANDING to basic php:

add:

```
action="Arrays.php"
```

to the form

then in Arrays.php:

```
$array_demo=array();//if the array is not already initialized.

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST['firstname']) && isset($_POST['lastname'])){
    $array_demo[{$_POST['firstname']}]= $_POST['lastname'];

}
```

Comment: im a slick guy, i buy lots of lube at the supermarket

Comment: I'll bet you were a Brylcreem guy too.